# how to access protected member of super class to its derived class. if a function already declared in the derived class with same name?

Tags: c++, function, class, inheritance, scope

I want to access protected member of Super Class in the following case. 
If anyone have any idea please let me know how can I achieve this? 
This protected function calls the protected function from the same class.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<String.h>
using namespace std;

/*Derived Class*/
class SuperParentClass
{

    protected:
        void protected_funtion()
        {
            cout << "I'm a protected function of SuperParentClass..." << endl;
        }

};

class ParentClass : public SuperParentClass
{

    public:


        void public_function(void)
        {
            cout << "I'm a public function of ParentClass..." << endl;
            protected_funtion();

        }

    protected:
        void protected_funtion()
        {
            cout << "I'm a protected function of ParentClass..." << endl;
        }

};


int main()
{
    ParentClass objParentClass;     
    objParentClass.public_function();     




    return 0;
}
```

Actual Result:

```
I'm a public function of Parent Class...
I'm a protected function of Parent Class...
```

Expected Result:

```
I'm a public function of Parent Class...
I'm a protected function of Super Parent Class...`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
void public_function(void)
{
   cout << "I'm a public function of ParentClass..." << endl;
   SuperParentClass::protected_funtion();

}
```

Live on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/lEaSH4)

Answer (score 0):

A function in a derived class with the same name as functions in the base class hides the functions in the base class.

So you need to use a qualified name to access a hidden function in the base class.

For example relative to your code you can write for example

```
void public_function(void)
{
    cout << "I'm a public function of ParentClass..." << endl;
    protected_funtion();
    SuperParentClass::protected_funtion();
}
```

If the functions having the same name differ in their types (otherwise an ambiguity can occur) then you can use the using declaration in the derived class to introduce the declarations of the functions in the base class. For example

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    void f() const
    {
        std::cout << "A::f()\n"; 
    }
};

struct B : A
{
    using A::f;

    void f()
    {
        std::cout << "B::f()\n"; 
    }

    void test()
    {
        f();

        const_cast<const B *>( this )->f();
    }
};

int main() 
{
    B().test();

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
B::f()
A::f()
```

Here without the using declaration in the class B the function f declared in the parent class A is hiden by the function declaration with the same name in the derived class B.

The using declaration allows to make visible the function f declared in the class A in the scope of the derived class B.